# Remove domain from HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name?

Tags: asp.net, iis

We have a third party application (YetAnotherForum) which we are using with Windows Authentication. The issue is that everyone's username is being prefixed with DOMAIN\. Is there a web.config setting which will stop ASP.NET including the domain name?

Thanks,

Joe

Comment: I don't think there's a setting, most solutions I've seen simply post-process the username stripping out the domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that you can remove the domain from the Name column in the yaf_User table and that will change the name that is shown on the forum. As long as you don't touch the yaf_prov_Membership table then it will still be tied back to the Active Directory user.